# VB.net Multiple Buttons using one function

Tags: vb.net, button, ctype, directcast

I dynamically rename buttons and I need to perform a function based on the button text. I have working code (5 sections for each button). Is there was good way to just use a single function for all 5 buttons using DirectCast or CType or really any other function so I don't have to have multiple functions that are doing the same thing?

My code example for two of the 5 buttons:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Button1.Text = "GO" Then
      MsgBox("GO")
    ElseIf Button1.Text = "STOP" Then
      MsgBox("STOP")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If Button2.Text = "GO" Then
      MsgBox("GO")
    ElseIf Button2.Text = "STOP" Then
      MsgBox("STOP")
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ctype etc works on Types not methods.  Just hook them up to the same handler

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple event handlers for the same event in VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588350/multiple-event-handlers-for-the-same-event-in-vb-net)

Comment: @varocarbas - Thanks, this worked for what I was doing.

Comment: @varocarbas Already covered in the dupe link.

Comment: Sorry will mark it in a bit. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Ah! you meant that one of the answers in the duplicated question is almost identical to my comment? I didn't realise about it; will better delete the comment.

Comment: @varocarbas Yes, but there's no need to delete your comment. It contains an important part: `same signature` ;)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Too late :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of direct reference Buton1 you can try this (Not sure about VB.NET sintax):

```
Dim myButton as Button
myButton=(button)sender
If myButton.Text = "GO" Then...
```